# jQuery addClass not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Does anybody know the solution for this code below ? It works in Chrome and Mozilla but doesnt work in IE. When I am in console I see that my class is not added.

```
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var navigation = $(".site-header");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50)  { // this refers to window
      navigation.addClass('bottom-shadow');
    } else 
      navigation.removeClass('bottom-shadow');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Tested it in IE11 and works https://jsfiddle.net/2hu3nt9L/ . Which IE version are you using ?

Comment: strange becaues for me it doesnt work in IE 11

Comment: Did you try the link i gave you ? Does it work ? if it does...it means that some other part of the code is causing the issue

Comment: Yes your code works in IE11. Yes it seems that the problem is somewhere else.. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: Are you sure you arent just rendering it in the wrong document mode? hit f12 and going into the document mode settings to see. For ie11 it should be set to edge

Comment: when I am in the console, classes are not added to inline styles like in chrome and FF